# Do convex combinations of projection matrices majorize the probability vector, i.e. $\sum_k p_k P_k\succeq \boldsymbol p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-geometry, projection-matrices, majorization

Consider a convex combination of normal projection matrices with positive coefficients: $$C\equiv \sum_k p_k P_k,$$
where $p_k>0$, $\sum_k p_k=1$, and $P_k=P_k^\dagger=P_k^2$.

If the $P_k$ are mutually orthogonal, *i.e.* $\newcommand{\tr}{{\operatorname{tr}}}\tr(P_j P_k)=\delta_{jk}$, then the (nonzero) eigenvalues of $C$ equal the coefficients $p_k$.

What can we say about the case of $P_k$ *not* mutually orthogonal? Do the eigenvalues *have* to be different than $(p_k)_k$ in this case? Can we say something about how "ordered" they are, that is, whether $\sigma(C)\succeq\boldsymbol p$, where $\sigma(C)$ is the vector of eigenvalues of $C$, $\boldsymbol p$ is the vector of coefficients $p_k$, and $\preceq$ refers to the majorization preordering?

The notation and orthogonality conventions used above assume rank-$1$ projections, *i.e.* $\tr(P_k)=1$. However, if this assumption turns out to not be relevant, feel free to lift it. If the projections have rank $r$, the orthogonality would then read instead $\tr(P_i P_j)=r \delta_{ij}$, and probably some degeneracies in the spectra will have to be dealt with.

---

As a concrete example,
consider the $2\times2$ projections $P_0,P_+$ defined as
$$\newcommand{\e}[1]{{\mathbf{e}_{#1}}}
P_0\equiv \e0\e0^*=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \\
P_+\equiv \e+(\e+)^* \equiv \frac12(\e0+\e1)(\e0+\e1)^*=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, for all $p\in[0,1]$, the eigenvalues of $C_p\equiv p P_0 + (1-p) P_+$  are
$\lambda_\pm = \frac12\left(1\pm \sqrt{p^2+(1-p)^2}\right)$, and thus $\boldsymbol\lambda\equiv\sigma(C_p)\succeq\boldsymbol p\equiv (p,1-p)$, as easily seen plotting the function:

[image]

we can clearly see that here the vector of eigenvalues of any convex combination of $P_0$ and $P_+$ majorizes the coefficients of the convex combination themselves.

Generating random convex combinations of projectors onto random vectors I also always find the result to hold: $\sigma(C)\succeq\boldsymbol p$.

Does this result hold in the general case? If so, how do we prove it?

Comment: @BenGrossmann in my application, yes, and this is also the regime I tested numerically (more precisely, I tested rank-1 projections), but if the result were to hold more generally that would also be great.

Comment: I just noticed your comment in the post about the trace. Also, any result on rank-1 projections can be generalized by "breaking up" any projection into the sum of (equally-weighted) rank-1 projections.'

Comment: @gIS Can you clarify what it means to have mutually orthogonal projection matrices? Does it have to do with the column spaces of the projection matrices or instead orthogonality as defined by some matrix inner product?

Comment: @paulinho I mean the relation included in the post: $\operatorname{tr}(P_i P_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Although I now realise this is specific for rank-1 matrices which is what I mostly had in mind. So I guess for rank-$r$ matrices the orthogonality would read $\operatorname{tr}(P_i P_j)=r\delta_{ij}$. It is orthogonality wrt the matrix inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(A^\dagger B)$. For projections this means that their supports/ranges are disjoint, thus diagonalizing is trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $\{p_i\}$ is decreasing. For any $r$ between $1$ and $n$, since the $P_i$s are rank-one orthogonal projections, $S_r=\sum_{i=1}^rp_iP_i$ is a positive semidefinite matrix of rank $\le r$. It follows that the sum of the largest $r$ eigenvalues of $S_r$ is equal to the trace of $S_r$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{k=1}^r\lambda_k^\downarrow(S_n)
\ge\sum_{k=1}^r\lambda_k^\downarrow(S_r)
=\operatorname{tr}(S_r)
=\sum_{k=1}^rp_k\tag{1}
$$
and equality holds when $r=n$. Thus $\lambda^\downarrow$ majorises $p$ from above. From $(1)$ we also obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-r}\lambda_k^\uparrow(S_n)
=\operatorname{tr}(S_n)-\sum_{k=1}^r\lambda_k^\downarrow(S_n)
\le
\operatorname{tr}(S_n)-\sum_{k=1}^rp_k
=\sum_{k=r+1}^n p_k.
$$
Therefore $p$ majorises $\lambda^\uparrow$ from below.

Comment: great, thanks! I didn't know there were two notions of majorization though ("from below" and "from above"). The wikipedia only mentions the "from below" one, and it seems only to generalise to the case in which the sum of the vectors is not equal. Does satisfying both these majorization conditions at the same time have interesting implications?

Comment: also, the definition on wikipedia of "majorization from below" seems to match your definition of "majorization from above". Which one is the correct terminology?

Comment: @glS I don't know whether there is a standard convention for majorisation. The version I remember (if correctly) is from Marshall and Olkin, who require that equality holds when $k=n$. In this case, majorisation of sequence A over sequence B from above (when both are arranged in decreasing order) is equivalent to majorisation of B over A from below (when both are arranged in increasing order). It seems that the equality constraint is not required in the Wikipedia entry. As for the phrase "from below/above", I believe it's only a colloquial term. It's hard to say which usage is correct.

Comment: I see. So to be clear, the two things you prove are not obviously equivalent, right? Because you are showing that $A\succ B$ from both above and below (rather than $A\succ B$ from above and $B\succ A$ from below)

Comment: @Oh, it's a typo. Will fix it.

Comment: ok, so proving both is only for completeness right? the two statements are equivalent for any pair of probability vectors (sorry for insisting, I'm often confused by these details so I want to make sure)

Comment: @glS Yes. If partial sum 1 $\ge$ partial sum 2 and the full sums are equal, then remaining sum 1 = full sum - partial sum 1 $\le$ full sum - partial sum 2 = remaining sum 2.